# Connector tunnel reset between SAP BTP and Cloud Connector

Tags: node.js, sap-business-technology-platform, s4hana, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-connector

I am running few services in SAP BTP CF using Node.js. From BTP CF we are trying to connect to on-premise S/4HANA using cloud connector. But some time the cloud connector logs show that tunnel restarts frequently. As a result the app throws 502, 503 and socket hang up frequently. Can someone help what could be the problem?